# Not able to load dataset as per the instructions in article

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I am new to data science field.
I came through this article 
https://towardsdatascience.com/train-test-split-and-cross-validation-in-python-80b61beca4b6
Here I am not able to load diabetes dataset as per the code they have written.

```
# Load the Diabetes dataset

columns = “age sex bmi map tc ldl hdl tch ltg glu”.split() # Declare the columns names
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes() # Call the diabetes dataset from sklearn
df = pd.DataFrame(diabetes.data, columns=columns) # load the dataset as a pandas data frame
y = diabetes.target # define the target variable (dependent variable) as y
```

I have tried to load data set through csv but in vain.

Comment: What happens when you try?  Do you get an error message?  Include it in your question.

Comment: Make sure that you use real quotation marks `"` to delimit strings, not `“` and `”,` as in your code fragment.

Answer (score 1):

As @DYZ mentioned it is the quotation marks issue, copy paste the below and run

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt



columns = "age sex bmi map tc ldl hdl tch ltg glu".split() # Declare the columns names
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes() # Call the diabetes dataset from sklearn
df = pd.DataFrame(diabetes.data, columns=columns) # load the dataset as a pandas data frame
y = diabetes.target # define the target variable (dependent variable) as y
```